# An URL used to inject a content script into web pages in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the manifest file of the Chrome extension "Search by Image", which allows you to search images on Google by just right clicking pictures on the web, the "content_scripts" field looks like this:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "css": [ "quimby.css" ],
  "js": [ "jquery-1.7.1.min.js", "quimby.js" ],
  "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls\u003E" ]
} ]
```

How does the match pattern "\u003Call_urls\u003E" work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`\u003C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c/index.htm) and [`\u003E`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3e/index.htm) are unicode characters. What it is matching is [`<all_urls>`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html)

Those files will be injected into every page that the extension has permission to modify.

Comment: Thanks, anstosa, but how about the `Call_urls` between `\u003` and `\u003E`? What does that mean?

Comment: The C is part of the first escaped unicode character. It's \u003C + all_urls + \u003E

Comment: Why does < and > need to be escaped?

Comment: @LoveRight - it doesn't, but I've came across many chrome-extensions having it this way, it is not the standard. Some Anti-Malware software analyse browser-side extensions for excessive permissions, it *might* be for some kind of obfuscation.. unless it doen't.. ;)